# In Magento 2 admin, how to set Custom Layout Option to a default value of ''No Update' value

Tags: magento2, magento-1, data-migration-tool

I recently did data migration from M1 to M2 with data migration tool. The product when opened in the edit mode from Admin would show "Use Existing" as the default value instead of "No Update" for Cusomt Layout Option under Migration_Default. The products would display only if the Custom Layout Option is No Update. I tried to set the this attribute for all the products using Update Attributes under Action dropdown, but it's not making any difference. Is there way to accomplish this? Please refer the screenshots. When a product gets saved with the custom layout update = No Update under Migration_design, the following tables would lose some records. I am not sure if there should be other table too that would also lose the entries.

1. catalog_product_entity_datetime - All the entries got deleted.
2. catalog_product_entity_decimal  - 6 record became 3
3. catalog_product_entity_int      - 17 records became 13
4. catalog_product_entity_text     - 7 became 6
5. catalog_product_entity_varchar  - 54 became 37

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table **eav_attribute**, you need to find **attribute_code = page_layout, entity_type_id = 4** to get the **attribute_id**.

After that, run this command:

```
delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = xxx
```

in that, **xxx = attribute_id** that you've got from the above table.

Comment: Hi LitExtension, grateful to you for your time. I found the attribute_id which is 107. I am little nervous if deleting this record will do any irrepairable damage to the system. Please advise me what precaution do I need to take before this action.

Comment: Don't worry, there will have no damage to the system. If you are still not sure, you can back up data by running this command: create table backup_layout as select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 107

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assurance along with the additional information.

Comment: Hi, The error is still there. Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'handle': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'

Comment: Do I need to do anymore than the steps you specified?

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, Could you please find an alternate solution?

Comment: @CodeForGood, could you please send a specific image of the errors?

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, image is pasted above the question. Strange enough, the error has nothing whatsoever to do with any XML file. As soon as I change the value for Custom Layout Update from Use Existing to No update, the product page displays perfectly.

Comment: @CodeForGood, now, you run the above delete command, after that, please run this command: insert into catalog_product_entity_varchar (store_id, value, attribute_id,entity_id) select 0, null,107, entity_id from catalog_product_entity

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration the above command for deletion was already run the day you first assisted. I am going to do it again followed by running the other insert SQL you provided now.

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, I did as advised by you. the error still persists.

Comment: We spend a lot of time trying to  figure this out hoping for a fix. Please look at the picture of the table added above for one of the products for you get a better understanding of the structure, thanks for your kind support and time.

Comment: @CodeForGood the attribute is incorrect, please try to run again the two above query with "attribute_id = 314"

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, we ran this command to work on just one product id, but i didn't make a difference.  delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 314 and entity_id=5019
insert into catalog_product_entity_varchar (store_id, value, attribute_id,entity_id) select 0, null,314, entity_id from catalog_product_entity where entity_id=5019

Comment: @CodeForGood you should clear cache first - if you still get error, please save one product and let it work. Then you take a picture of that product's table "product_entity_varchar" and send me

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, Cleared the cache. Error still persists. Saved a product by choosing "No Update" which makes the product work as you know. Attached are the table for this particular product.

Comment: I can't find any attribute layout in your image

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, please have a look at the screenshot of the eav_attribute table displaying layout attribute.

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, I found some tables such as  catalog_product_entity_varcha with much less data than what should have been. We verified this by comparing the tables between Magento 1 and Magento 2. I am going to rerun the data migration. I would seek your advises to keep in min while doing data migration using data migration tool. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, your suggestions and advises have helped us find out the root cause of the problem, we will hopefully fix it shortly.

Comment: @CodeForGood, it's our pleasure, hope you will fix it successfully!

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, I have just finished redoing the migration which didn't help fix this error. I have pasted the table that shows the custom layout records. I will do your suggestion once again tomorrow.

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, I noticed that there was no attribute_id = 315 in the the same table from the previous data migration. You can see that there are two custom_layout_update_file under atrribute_code. I think something around will fix our issue. Kindly have a look at it. thanks

Comment: @CodeForGood sorry to hear it. Honestly, as I tested the Magento data migration tool before, I met many errors and really unsatisfied with this tool. Moreover, there is no immediate support when having issues, so the migration process took a lot of time. In case you can't fix those issues, I recommend you to try and run a free demo of LitExtension migration tool, the support team is always available to support you!

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, thanks for the message. I am happy to inform you that the issue got finally fixed when we found the cause of this issue associated with the table catalog_product_entity_text. 106  was the attribute code in Magento 1 for custom_layout_update which should have been changed by the migration tool to 313. We removed this attribute_id= 106   from eav_attribute, catalog_product_entity_varchar and catalog_product_entity_varchar, which enable all the product pages to display properly.

Comment: I must agree that my investigation into this issue was really inspired by your suggestion otherwise this would have taken me much longer.

Comment: @ LitExtension Magento Migration, hi could you please share your insights into how to solve this one. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309612/the-attribute-target-in-tag-a-is-set-to-the-invalid-value-about-blank

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution to the question at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325884/magento-2-3-4-how-to-trim-the-order-confirmation-number/325892?noredirect=1#comment466143_325892

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to run these two SQL statements.

```
* DELETE * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_id = 106;
* DELETE * FROM catalog_product_entity_text table where attribute_id=106;
```