# Magento 2.3.4: How to shorten the external order increment ID?

Tags: magento2.3, php

The confirmations numbers(order increment ID) come through as 1000000936(6 zeros) when a customer places an order on our online store. I want to remove 3 of those zeros for all the coming order number so that we and the customer both see confirmation numbers like 1000936. Please tell me which table in Magento DB is to be edited and how or show me any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

In `eav_entity_type` table,By default increment id length is 8. So Order Id has 8 0s.

You need to change the length value in `eav_entity_type` table.

First run this query
`SELECT * FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_id =5;`
entity_type_id 5 mentions sales/order.

By default `increment_pad_length` value is 8,you need to change it from 8 to 4 for your need.

change `increment_pad_length` value by run this query

`UPDATE eav_entity_type SET increment_pad_length = 4 WHERE entity_type_id =5;`

I think it will help you..

Also You can take a look at - https://www.classyllama.com/blog/m2-incrementid

Comment: Hi, tried this to no avail. Same old length of the increment ID still comes up.

Comment: Cleared cache & tried ?

Comment: Good point, I didn't clear the cache.

Comment: I see this untracked file on the server app/etc/.env.php.swp What should I do with this?

Comment: Same result even after clearing Magento cache.

Comment: tried with placing new order ?

Comment: Yes, new order comes with the old format of confirmation number.

Comment: Following your answer appears to have worked except that the length of the increment ID remains. In the past, the order increment ID used to be something like 1000000876 while the new order increment ID comes up as 1001000877. I don't want first `100` How can I address this?